# Increase accuracy of QR code reading

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have an Android application in which Implement zxing for reading QR codes. Everything works great for me, the implementation had no problem, either edit the views and results as I wanted. But I realized that when the QR is poor or there are many codes at a moderate distance near the reader does not work very well. Cuesta read, and I'm much delay is a bit problematic for me to spend my application. My application is a ticket validator marathons, festivals, etc. So time is precious for me. I wonder if there is a parameter that makes more accurately read codes or any way to make reading more accurate. I'm working on this case, with a 3rd generation Motorola Motog so the hardware is not so bad. For the results of the reading I hold the following function library.

```
private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult,ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode)throws URISyntaxException {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current recommendation is to use the [Android Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview), which works [locally](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html) (offline), [without](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes) requiring a server roundtrip. It's probably also more accurate than Zxing.

> The Barcode API detects barcodes in real-time, on device, in any orientation. It can also detect multiple barcodes at once.
>
> It reads the following barcode formats:
>
> - 1D barcodes: EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar
> - 2D barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC
>
> It automatically parses QR Codes, Data Matrix, PDF-417, and Aztec values, for the following supported formats:
>
> - URL
> - Contact information (VCARD, etc.)
> - Calendar event
> - Email
> - Phone
> - SMS
> - ISBN
> - WiFi
> - Geo-location (latitude and longitude)
> - AAMVA driver license/ID